# Incorporate regex quantifier into brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to incorporate the following negative lookahead regex

```
^(?!\*\*)
```

into the following regex

```
^([a-z]:)?(\\[^<>:"/\\|?;,$=%@~]+)+\\?$
```

Basically, I don't want two consecutive asterisks (`**`) to appear anywhere in the file path. How do I modify the block `[^<>:"/\\|?;,$=%@~]` to incorporate this condition? I tried using escape characters, but to no avail.

Comment: So, like you want to let control characters into the file path `[^<>:"/\\|?;,$=%@~]` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this as a negative look-ahead at the beginning of the second pattern:

```
^(?!.*\*\*)([a-z]:)?(\\[^<>:"/\\|?;,$=%@~]+)+\\?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD0bF9/1)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want two consecutive asterisk (`**`) to appear anywhere in the file path

Just prefix this negative lookahead before your regex:

```
/^(?!.*?\*\*)([a-z]:)?(\\[^<>:"/\\|?;,$=%@~]+)+\\?$/mg
```

`(?!.*?\*\*)` after `^` will avoid matching the input if there are two `*` in the input.